# multi select on change from array with selectors

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors, onchange, multi-select

On a form that I am creating, I have multiple select boxes where the user can select multiple items from. Like I do with all the other inputs on the form. I make an array of all the selectors of the types of inputs and then go over each selector and check for an input change. But I am encountering an issue with the multi select input.

```js
// Multiselect
var multiSelect = [];
multiSelect.push('#specialties');

$.each(multiSelect, function(index, value) {

    console.info({ value }); // Outputs: '#specialties'

    // This fires
    $('#specialities').change(function(){
      console.info('test');
    });

    // This does not fire?
    $(value).change(function(){
      console.info('test');
    });

});
```

In the above code, I create an empty array. Then I push all the elements (I only have one for simplicity of the example.)
Then for each of the items in the array I output the current `value` for testing. In the console I can see that it outputs `'#specialties'`
Then I want to detect the change like this:

```js
$(value).change(function(){
    console.info('test');
});
```

But for some reason it does not detect the change. Whenever I put in the ID instead of `value` it does fire.

```js
$('#specialties').change(function(){
    console.info('test');
});
```

Anyone any idea why this is. As far as I know, `value` and `'#specialties'` are the exact same thing. But I don't know everything, so I might learn a few new things when asking this question.

**THE PROBLEM WAS A TYPO**

My code was not working because I made a freaking typo on the third line. I wrote `#specialties` and I should have written `#specialities` notice the extra i.

Nonetheless, the solution provided by mplungjan is my accepted solution. Although, it ignores the array completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works

```js
// Multiselect
var multiSelect = [];
multiSelect.push('#specialties');

$.each(multiSelect, function(index, value) {

  console.info({value}); // Outputs: '#specialties'

 
  // This ALSO fires
  $(value).change(function() {
    console.info('test');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="specialties" multiple>
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Here is a better version

```js
$(function() {
  $("#container").on("change", "select", function(e) {
    const selectedValues = $(this).val();
    console.log(Array.isArray(selectedValues) ? selectedValues.join(",") : selectedValues)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <select id="specialties" multiple>
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution and I tried it, and it works great. I don't understand why my code works in SO but not in the application I am building, but anyhow, I am happy to go with your code. Am I right in saying that your code does nothing with `var multiSelect = ['specialties'];`?

Comment: True. I will remove it unless you want to use it